# Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a base class called IntList, in a IntList.h file. And a inherited class called SortedSet in a SortedSet.h file.
The IntList has the following struct :-

```
struct IntNode
{
    int data;
    IntNode *next;
    IntNode( int data ) : data(data), next(0) {}
};
```

The following code is a friend function in the SortedSet class. This function returns a SortedSet object that is the union of 2 SortedSet objects, the left and right operands of this binary operator.

```
SortedSet operator|(const SortedSet &lho, const SortedSet &rho)
{
    SortedSet temp;
    IntNode* set1 = lho.head;
    IntNode* set2 = rho.head;

    while(set1->next != 0)
    {
        temp.push_back(set1->data);
        set1 = set1->next;
    }

    delete set1;

    while(set2->next != 0)
    {
        if (temp.in(set2->data) == false)
        {
            temp.push_back(set2->data);
            //cout<<"It isn't in there"<<endl;
        }
        set2 = set2->next;
    }
    delete set2;

    return temp;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault, and I can't seem to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Can you post a call stack?

Comment: what do you mean? how i call it through main?

Comment: You shouldn't delete nodes that belong to the parameters. It's very rude.

Comment: Even when I remove the delete part, i still get the segmentation fault errors

Comment: prior to dereferencing, check whether one of your pointers is null, i.e. `set1` or `set2`. dereferencing a null pointer is probably the most common reason for segfaults.

Comment: At what line is the segmentation fault occurring?  Is it even in the code you have posted or does it occur later after the listed function returns? Either look at the call stack or step through the code to find out.  I imagine not posting this information is the reason for the down votes.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious error in your code is that you test that `set1->next` is not null when you should be testing that `set1` is not null.  From the limited information you have posted it is hard to be sure that this is the only problem, but this will almost certainly cause a segmentation fault so I am relatively confident that this is the problem.

Change your while loops to look like this:

```
while(set1 != 0)
{
    temp.push_back(set1->data);
    set1 = set1->next;
}
```

Then slap yourself in the forehead because this would have been very easy to pick up with a quick application of the debugger.

EDIT: You should also remove the `delete` operations because they will always be acting on a null pointer.  It's not clear why you would want to delete just one element of your list anyway so perhaps what you think you are doing doesn't need doing, although with no information about the workings of `SortedSet` it is hard to know.